# Do verification emails apply to the AWS Cognito daily email quota?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-ses

In AWS Cognito, the service notes that one should use Amazon SES for user pools due to the daily email limit of Cognito, [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTGs7.png). The quotas documentation shows that the maximum amount of emails sent per day is **50**.

In the '[Configuring Email or Phone Verification docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html)', it states that [there is **no charge** for sending verification codes to email addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QPo3.png). This documentation does not explicitly bring up Cognito email quotas.

I cannot find a clear answer as to whether or not verification code emails apply to the quota. I'm trying to avoid a situation in which  >50 users try to sign up in a day, but cannot receive their verification email. Can anyone clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you find solution ?

Comment: No, still trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

I've just confirmed that the limit applies to the verification emails as well. After signing up 50 users, the following message is received after user signup:

> An error occurred (LimitExceededException) when calling the AdminCreateUser operation (reached max retries: 2): Exceeded daily email limit for the operation or the account. If a higher limit is required, please configure your user pool to use your own Amazon SES configuration for sending email.

Similarly if the signup occurs via the Hosted UI, except it only mentions `An error was encountered with the requested page.`.

Worth mentioning that the Sign up still occurs, ie, the user is still created in the User Pool but no verification email is sent. Also, password recovery emails cannot be sent after this limit is reached, as the limit is shared and is **per account**, so applicable across all user pools in same account.